# Qt Creator not responding upon startup for a few minutes

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Not a VERY big deal, but it's still annoying. Qt Creator shows Not Responding for a few minutes upon startup, then it's OK. What could be the reason? How to fix it? I have cleared my temp files, also have given Qt Creator admin rights. It still does not help. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Tried disabling the welcome screen as per the suggestion. Now the welcome screen does not show up, but I still have the same problem:

[image]

Comment: Without an OS (I'm guessing Windows something) or version, it is hard to pin down, but it could be related to these bugs [Qt Creator freezes at startup](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20595) or [Qt Creator is a bit slow to open](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20593).

Comment: It's specific to your system. Use system-specific tools to see where it's stuck (you'd use strace on unix).

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is likely the "welcome" screen.

Go to `help - about plugins` and disable `welcome`.

Another source of delays might be due to an internet connection being unable to go through and waiting to time out.

It is normal if the first time Creator is started to take a little longer while scanning for external tools, but after the initial run it should not be a problem.

As the comment noted, it might be the case of a recently introduced issue, in the case you are running the affectd version - 4.6.1.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Please see my second screenshot. Thank you!

Comment: @armanali, you could test if the issue was some weird internet connection issue by disabling all internet connections (lan, wifi, et c.) and then firing up Qt Creator.  This would test Qt Creator in the absence of connections.

Comment: @RossRogers, put the laptop in Airplane Mode. Still happening. Disabled as many plugins as possible, but it's still happening.

Comment: @RossRogers, :D

Comment: Why on earth is something like enable Plugins hidden under "Help" and not a panel in the regular Options?  Madness.  Thanks for pointing it out so I can turn off all the things I have no intent to use.

Answer (score 2):

For those observing instances of the problem with versions 4.8 and upwards running on Windows 10, I can confirm Windows Defender having a role in it.

Disabling the Welcome Plugin does not always solve the problem, as this is also triggered by first-open of the File menù (which populates Recent Files/Projects submenus) or often by simply hitting `Ctrl+K`.

My solution consisted in adding Qt Creator to the Windows Defender exclusion list.

This is done by navigating **Windows Security** -> **Virus & threat protection** -> **Virus & threat protection settings** -> **Exclusions**.

Then add a **Process** exclusion entry using the path to the Qt Creator binary directory, such as `C:\Qt\qtcreator-4.9.0\bin\*`. 
Note the presence of the final `\*` bit, to whitelist all binaries in that directory.

Comment: I agree that an anti-virus program is probably the culprit here, although it is not necessarily Windows Defender. I had a similar problem with BullGuard, which I ended up having to disable completely.